# Нужно выделить самое длинное слово и переставить на первое место

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251 >> NUL");

    setlocale(0, "RU");
    char str[100];
    printf("Введите вашу строку:\n");
    gets_s(str);
    char sp[] = " ,-/;:)_=+`[]{}()'.";
    char* token;

    token = strtok(str, sp); 

    while (token != NULL)

    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL , sp);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Сделал пока так,не совсем понимаю как правильно достать подстроку из строки.В цикле while у меня строка дробится на слова с помощью strtok ,а вот дальше что-то не могу сообразить что делать. 
P.S.первый курс,не кидайте тапками:)Заранее спасибо

Comment: Найдите самое большое слово, далее собирайте новую строку, memcpy Вам поможет) Сначала копируйте нужное слово, потом, что было до него, потом все что после него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100], tmp[100]="", result[100]="";
    char sp[] = " .,;:=+`[]{}()_-/\'";
    int count=0, max=0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("Введите строку: \n");
    gets(str);
    printf("\nИсходная строка: %s\n", str);
    strcpy(tmp, str);   // сохраним исходную строку в tmp

    // первый проход - находим максимальную длину слова max
    char *token = strtok(str, sp);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
    //  printf("%s\n", token);
        count = strlen(token);
        if(count > max)
            max = count;
    //  printf("%i\n", count);
        token = strtok(NULL, sp);
    }
    strcpy(str, tmp);   // восстановим исходную строку в str
    strcpy(tmp, "");

    // второй проход - формируем строку результата
    token = strtok(str, sp);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        count = strlen(token);
        if(count == max) {
            strcat(result, token);  // строку максимальной длины поместим в "голову"
            strcat(result, ",");    // добавим разделитель
        }
        else {
            strcat(tmp, token);     // строку меньшей длины, чем max, поместим в "хвост"
            strcat(tmp, ",");
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, sp);
    }
    count = strlen(tmp);            // длина "хвоста"
    strncat(result, tmp, count-1);  // соединим "горову" и "хвост", отбросив последний разделитель
    printf("Результат: %s\n", result);

    printf("\nPress <Enter> to continue... ");
    gets(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Использовать strcat неэффективно...

Comment: А ещё ты все самые длинные слова переместишь в начало.

Comment: Qwertiy: Таково задание. Если в строке присутствуют два или более слов максимальной длины, какое из них считать самым длинным? Все равноправны и идут в начало.

Comment: Ну я бы предположил, что любое, но только одно. Так же непонятно, что делать с разделителями. Вроде бы не сказано, что их надо сохранять, но вполне может оказаться, что надо.

Comment: Чтобы только одно слово макс.длины переместить в начало, достаточно использовать флажок. Для задания начального уровня сохранение разделителей усложняет программу, хотя, если используется единственный разделитель, то автору вопроса есть над чем поразмышлять.